# missing methods in datastax driver example

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax

This is taken directly from datastax driver example

```
Statement statement = QueryBuilder.update("simplex", "songs")
    .with(set("artist", "Vasili Ostertag"))
    .where(eq("id", UUID.fromString("f6071e72-48ec-4fcb-bf3e-379c8a696488")));
getSession().execute(statement);
```

You can see this line references two methods set and eq, neither is explained anywhere that I can see. I have looked thru this github 
    https://github.com/jbisso/cassandra-samples
but don't find the answer.

Any one knows how to complete this code? there must be some missing import statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those can be found in [QueryBuilder](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html)

You can import all:

```
import static com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.*;
```